# Is it bad to use the built-in python on mac?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I started learning python on a PC, by installing Python 3, and so when I switched to mac I thought "Look at that, you can just type idle in the terminal and there's Python 2, let me just use that," not wanting to have to deal with two versions on the same machine. However, I read that it's recommended to install a newer version of Python and not to mess up with the built-in install.
Is it a bad practice to use the built-in version? For the matter, I'm not a heavy programmer, just like to play with Python every now and then. The only extra module I've installed was Pillow.

Comment: You asking is it bad to use both versions of Python?

Comment: No, just if it's bad to be using the built-in one.

Comment: You'll be fine w/the bundled version if you want to learn Python 2.  Installing and using a recent Python 3.4 is best for future-oriented learning, but 2.7 and 3.4 are 99% the same, so I personally wouldn't obsess about it... even though Py3 **is** substantially better, at work and on Google App Engine I still use 2.7 daily, and I don't feel "terrible" about it (inc. using it on my Macs!-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in Python, there's nothing "bad" about it.  If someday you run into some limitation (unlikely), you can always switch then.

Answer (score 1):

As for me it isn't so bad, but it's not handy when you make deal with more then one project. 
How to figure it out? 
First of all, install [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/). I'm also using [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to work with virtualenvs more convinent way. The main idea of virtualenv is to make every project have its own interpeter with set of libs its only needed.
And if you want to have multiple versions of python install [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv).

It may looks redundantly, but believe - it won't be a pain to start using it, but it will make your work more clear and handy.